# How to plot POLYGONS on a go.Scattermapbox

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, polygon

I have a scattermapbox plot and would like to add some polygons (convex hulls) on there.

The polygon data looks like:

```
1      POLYGON ((13.77168 45.55315, 13.76797 45.55402, 13.76898 45.55429, 13.77202 45.55397, 13.77309 4...
2      POLYGON ((11.99333 51.47548, 11.98722 51.48514, 11.98768 51.48617, 11.98827 51.48736, 11.98868 5...
3      POLYGON ((7.47432 51.53960, 7.48201 51.54153, 7.48322 51.54149, 7.48975 51.54121, 7.48924 51.540...
```

First drawing some base data (X) on a map with:

```
fig = FigureResampler(
                go.Figure(
                go.Scattermapbox(
                        lat=X["location_latitude"], 
                        lon=X["location_longitude"],
                        mode='markers',
                        marker=dict(size=size, color=X["cluster_label"]),             
                        )
                )
        )
```

As I think, adding the planes is best via another scattermapbox plane (correct?):

```
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scattermapbox(
                 mode = "lines", fill = "toself",
                 lat= ...
                 lon= ...)
)
```

But as you can see I left out the lat and lon. Do I have to extract each lat lon from each polygon?

**Could you hint me how to extract only the lat and lon from the polygons?**

Second,
What would be best way to assemble it? Storing all lats for each polygon in a "lat" column and lon in a "lon" column (let's say the data frame is called *polygons*) and then call:

```
fig.add_trace(
        go.Scattermapbox(
                 mode = "lines", fill = "toself",
                 lat= polygons["lat"]
                 lon= polygons["lon"])
)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: The examples in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-on-mapbox/#geojson-layers) will be helpful. If you can provide complete polygon information and user data, we may be able to help.

Comment: Wow that looks great. Thanks for the link. I will try this and add any knowledge I gained. Also, I might have found another solution and will add it as soon as I can confirm that it works.